How to compute the characteristic function of a Brownian motion at a random time?

Let $B,W$ be two real valued independent linear Brownian motions starting from $0$ and $T_1=\inf\{t\geq 0: W_t=1\}$.
I want to show that for any $s\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\mathbb{E}(\exp(isB_{T_1}))=\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}s^2 T_1\right)\right)$$  by conditioning w.r.t $T_1$.

My problem is, that I don't really know where to start, I know that $$\mathbb{E}(\exp(isB_{T_1}))=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}(\exp(isB_{T_1}))\middle|\mathcal{F}_{T_1}\right)$$ by the tower property, but then I don't know how to continue, in the discrete case I could consider the event $1_{T_1=t_1}$ and then condition on this "discrete event" but here we are i the continuous case so this does not work. I thought about using that they $B$ and $W$ are independent so in particular $B$ and $T_1$ are independent but this does not help me much. What I also could show that that if we denote by $f_{T_1}, f_B$ the densities then $$\mathbb{E}(\exp(isB_{T_1}))=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{E}(\exp(isB_y))f_{T_1}(y)~dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}ys^2}f_{T_1}(y)~dy$$ but here I don't use conditioning and I want to use it. Could someone help me how to do it by conditioning on $T_1$?

$T_1$ is independent of $(B_t)_t$. And $\mathbb{E}(\exp(isB_{t}))=\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}s^2 t\right)\right)$. These two facts are enough to say that $\mathbb{E}(\exp(isB_{T_1}))=\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}s^2 T_1\right)\right)$. You just have to integrate the first equation w.r.t. the distribution of $T_1$.

But I don't know the distribution of $T_1$ respectively it's density function.

You don't need any of that.
